# Why is my start method undefined for the timer class?

Tags: java

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.Timer.*;

class Timer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 20;
        final JTextField textField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);

        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(textField);

        ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                Date now = new Date();
                textField.setText(now.toString());
            }
        };

        final int DELAY = 1000;

        Timer t = new Timer();
        t.start();

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

It could be a syntax error, but I don't think so because I copied this program straight out of a book. The line of code, 't.start();' has an error line under it saying that the start() method is undefined. At first, I thought that the start() method didn't exist, but I looked it up in the library.

Comment: It would *really* help if you'd indent all your code sensibly.

Comment: What's wrong with the way that it is indented?

Comment: What's wrong is that it is hardly indented at all. Code inside `{` and `}` should be indented one indent more than the `{` and `}.` It's clear from the classname confusion that you didn't just 'copy this program straight out of a book' at all: you changed things.

Comment: @igknighton: Less now that Richard Tingle has indented it for you (although I'll improve it further). The first version was horrible. But Stack Overflow doesn't handle tabs very nicely - you should convert them to spaces before posting, and *use the preview* to check that your code looks okay.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you're declaring your *own* `Timer` class - so `Timer t = new Timer()` is referring to your class rather than `javax.swing.Timer`, and you don't declare a `start` method. I'm pretty sure you want to use the `javax.swing.Timer` class instead. So you want to remove the `import javax.swing.Timer.*;` line, and rename your `Timer` class to something else.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TimerTest {
    ...
}
```

Having said that, you're not telling your timer to *do* anything...

Answer (score 0):

While [Skeet's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19134038/887149) is correct, you can solve it another way. Change initialization of `timer` to

```
javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(DELAY, listener);
t.start();
```

Comment: That would work - but cause needless confusion, IMO. Given that the class he's declaring is *not* in itself a timer, it's a bad idea to *call* it `Timer`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: you are right. This would be inappropriate for this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps to make your code gets executed :

```
Change your class name to some other name.
```

Note: After changing the class name you will be getting a compilation error saying that there is an ambiguity of using the Timer class. As you have imported both the util and swing packages (These two packages contains the Timer Class).

Now Change your line of code to

```
Timer t = new Timer();
```

as

```
javax.swing.Timer t = new javax.swing.Timer(DELAY, listener);
t.start();
```